# Is Windows in text input mode?

Tags: c++, winapi

I need a reliable way to determine if I type a character it will appear on the screen, i.e. in a textbox or other input control (in any process). This needs to work for Browsers too which seem to have their own input elements.

I have tried using the accessibility api but that does not seem reliable using it to check for a text box.

I have also tried using `GetGUIThreadInfo` to get the caret position, again this is not reliable.

Any suggestions how to check if there is any type of input box visible that has the keyboard focus?

**Reason:** I'm adding the use case for this problem. We have a background accessibility process that monitors all keyboard input. (The user is fully aware of this process and can modify what happens to the input) In some situations the input is removed (by backspace) and replaced by something else. When there is no input box with the focus we do not want or need to send the backspace(s) required.

Comment: I can't think of any possible way to determine whether whatever is currently receiving keyboard input focus will do with the typed-in character. I'm afraid that this is completely un-possible. Now, what is the real problem are you trying to solve? No, not the one about determining what happens with the typed-in character. It's the problem to which you believe the solution is to determine what will happen with a typed-in character, so that's what you're asking about. Perhaps if you explain what the real problem is, a simple answer will be possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - added use case.

Comment: I think the back space is the problem. Can't you use a hook and modify the input before any apps see it?

Comment: @MichaelT Maybe [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `IUIAutomation::GetFocusedElement()`, `IUIAutomationElement::get_CurrentControlType()`, then compare with edit control type?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, `UI Automation` works when it works - there are many apps, chrome plus others that dont support `UI Automation`. Is there a way to know if the current process supports `UI Automation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated. detecting when a control can handle backspace is not very reliable. However tuning the problem on it's head helped.. detecting when a control can NOT handle backspace is fairly easy to do for our requirements.

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&uiAutomation_));
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(hr);
```

then

```
CONTROLTYPEID controlTypeID;
IUIAutomationElement * focusedElement;
if (SUCCEEDED(uiAutomation_->GetFocusedElement(&focusedElement)))
{
    focusedElement->get_CurrentControlType(&controlTypeID);
}

return controlTypeID == UIA_PaneControlTypeId ||
    controlTypeID == UIA_ListItemControlTypeId ||
    controlTypeID == UIA_DataItemControlTypeId ||
    controlTypeID == UIA_TextControlTypeId ||
    controlTypeID == UIA_ButtonControlTypeId;
```